# Refresh Current UIViewController from another view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

my problem is that I want to apply some settings to my running app on-the-fly.
I found a lot of tutorials on how to refresh the TableController, but this is not the case.

I have a UIViewController with some labels inside and one button, when I press the button I open as PopOver (so inside the current View) another ViewController, my settings page Controller. From here I can choose the color of the text labels and the language to apply in App.
Unfortunately I do not know how to apply this settings immediately.

Any help, with some code, would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should transfer instance of parent controller to popover.

```
func showPopover() {
     var settingController = ...
     var popoverController = ...
     settingController.parentController = self
     //show popover
     ...
}
```

In SettingController, you will have a variance parentController

Or you can refresh parent controller by override willViewAppear, didViewAppear.

Edit

(1)

```
@protocol MyDelegate {
    -(void) refreshLable:(UIColor*)color;
}
@implement ParentController<MyDelegate>  {
    - (IBAction) showPopover {
         ChildController *childController = ...
          childController.delegate = self;
         ...//Show popover
     }
    - (void) refreshLabel:(UIColor *) color {
       //Implement protocol with update label
    }
}
@implement ChildController {
    MyDelegate *delegate;
    - (IBAction) changeColor {
         Color *color=...
         if (delegate != null) [delegate changeLabel:color];
    }
}
```

(2)

```
@implement ChildController {
    - (IBAction) changeColor {
         Color *color=...
         [[SystemManager instance] setColor: color]; 
         //Here SystemManager instance if static variable
    }
}
@implement ParentController {
    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
         [super viewWillAppear:animated];
         //Get color from static variable
         UIColor *color = [[SystemManager instance] getColor];
         //Update label here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but can you edit your comment and writing how can I override the Appears? Sorry for the question, but I am completely out of brain at the moment!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am trying to translate this in Swift